# How do I punctuate a sentence that contains a quotation with a question mark?

Tags: punctuation

What is the correct punctuation surrounding the quoted question in this example:

> When a neighbor asks, "When are we getting together?" that is the beginning of building community.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is correct in both American and British English.

In English:

- commas replace full stops in quotations, but not exclamation or question marks

Therefore the following are all correct:

> When a neighbor says, "We are getting together," that is the beginning of building community. (American English)
> When a neighbor says, "We are getting together", that is the beginning of building community. (British English)
> When a neighbor asks, "When are we getting together?" that is the beginning of building community. (British and American English)

But it *looks* strange not to have commas on both sides of the quotation, and in fact the last clause has a longer pause before it, when you speak it, and might be better offset with a dash:

> Getting together – that is the beginning of building community.
> When a neighbor asks, "When are we getting together?" – that is the beginning of building community.

Comment: Thank you. Your two suggestions of no comma following the question mark and quotations mark, and using a dash were my two ideas. As I understand you, either would work, but the dash provides a longer pause, right?

Comment: @Janet Without dash, the sentence is just a simple statement: "Getting together is the beginning of building community." With dash there is an emphasis: "Getting together – *that* is the beginning of building community." You emphasize the singular importance of getting together. (Or of a neighbor asking about getting together, in your original example.)